# Как выбрать с SQL таблицы самого старшего человека

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте знатоки SQL

Есть таблица **`|employee_id|last_name|first_name|birth_date|photo|notes|`**

Как мне вывести самого старшего человека с полями: `last_name`, `first_name`?

Пишу так
**`SELECT MAX(birth_date), last_name, first_name  FROM employees`**

Выдает ошибку:

```
 Column "LAST_NAME" must be in the GROUP BY list; SQL statement:

    /* Feel free to remove this comment and write your solution here */
    SELECT MAX(birth_date), last_name, first_name  FROM employees  [90016-200]
```

Как это исправить? Спасибо.

Comment: *Как мне вывести самого старшего человека* `SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY birth_date LIMIT 1`

Comment: @Akina, только DESC

Comment: @Egorithm Старший - это с минимальным датом рождения. Так что ни разу не DESC.

Comment: @Akina, точно, время то в секундах с 70го.

Answer (score 1):

Решил:)))

```
SELECT last_name,first_name
FROM employees
WHERE birth_date = (SELECT min(birth_date) FROM employees )
```

Comment: подзапрос там был не нужен

Comment: А как без подзапроса? Можете написать? спасибо.